# Can't log in as registered user (php and mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, registration

I'm trying to do a log in and registration script. I've managed to finish most of it; however, after I register a user I am unable to log in as that user. That is, registered users are unable to log in. Any help would be massively appreciated! :)

This is the code that relates to the specific problem:

```
$login = login ($username, $password);
        if ($login === false) {
         $errors [] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect';
        } else {
           $_SESSION ['user_id'] = $login;
           header ('Location: index.php');
           exit (); 
    }       


function  login ($username, $password) {
   $user_id = user_id_from_username ($username);

   $username = sanitize ($username);
   $password = md5($password);

return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE username =     '$username' AND password = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
}
```

I wrote the query above like this (BELOW), earlier. Writing it this way allowed me to log in but with "literally" any password.

```
function login ($username, $password){ 
  $user_id = user_id_from_username ($username);

  $username = sanitize ($username); 
  $password = sanitize ($password); 

  $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE username =     '$username'"); 

 $query2 =  mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE password = '$password'"); 

 return  (mysql_result($query1, 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false; 
 return (mysql_result($query2, 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
```

That is to say, I broke the query down into two parts, but noticed the password query was completely irrelevant (even if I "commented" it out).

PS. I know I should be using PDO or Mysqli instead of mysql queries, and that md5 isn’t that secure.  Just ignore these things for the sake of this riddle.

Comment: Security vulnerabilities are generally more important to fix than bugs.

Comment: So what actual problem are you having?  Can't you point to a specific line in your code where you are encountering problems?

Comment: Why do you have both a `user_id_from_username` function (which I assume does a DB lookup for the user_id) and then ANOTHER DB query to compare the password.  Just do one query to look up the user / password combo and SELECT the id (not a count). If you get a row then you have a match otherwise you fail the login attempt.

Comment: @WaleedKhan not if it's a personal project.

Comment: so what's the output of your query? and when you run the sql query to your db?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! @Mike. The line causing the most frustration  is the query in the login function ("function login"). Both a username and password are stored in my database, however when I try to log in with that information it says the username/password combination are wrong. I've tried rewriting the query many different ways to no avail. I've also tried logging in by copying and pasting the information from the database.

Comment: @BernieAllen So what debugging have you done? Have you tried to print out an actual query that is being created and tried to run it against the database?  Is `user_id_from_username()` giving you the correct result?

Comment: @artsylar When I try to echo the result of the query I just get a blank white screen.

Comment: thanks @BernieAllen for the info. But have you tried to run the query directly to your db? so what is the output?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Mike. I just ran the query through PhpMyadmin and it gave me this: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `passwo' at line 1"

Comment: @BernieAllen Also a word of advice regarding the DB connection (outside of the mysql vs. mysqli/PDO issue).  When making queries like this, you REALLY should make sure you are include proper error handling and edge case handling.  Evaluating your query result with a loose comparison is a REALLY bad idea.  Also trying to jam all your DB query code into one line makes the code hard to read, and ultimately harder for you to debug. There are no points awarded for cramming multiple operations into a single line of code. Break them apart and handle the responses individually with logging and such.

Comment: @BernieAllen You need to try the DB query with the actual query being run (i.e. with your variable data in place of your variable names.

Comment: so you already executed this query on your db already and still getting the same error? SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE username =     'sample_user' AND password = 'sample_password'

Comment: @artslar I ran the query  through phpmyadmin and it gave me:  "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND `passwo' at line 1". ... I'm not really sure what to make of it.

Comment: I wrote the query above like this (BELOW), earlier. It allowed me to log in but with literally any password.  function login ($username, $password){
$user_id = user_id_from_username ($username);

   $username = sanitize ($username);
   $password = sanitize ($password);   

   $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"); 
   $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `password` = '$password'"); 
   return (mysql_result($query1, 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
   return (mysql_result($query2, 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;

Comment: That is to say, I broke the query down into two parts, but noticed the password query was completely irrelevant (even if I commented it out). I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Could you please add that new code to your question so it'll be more readable? thanks!

Comment: Don't bother with that old code.  It is worthless as you need to check for the combination of username and password.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mike! I tried what you wrote and there were no errors, but it still wouldn't work. I changed your code a bit in an attempt to make it work and I'm still getting that the 'username and password don't match.' I appended to my initial question (above).

I don't think this is a problem with the queries or functions at all as the only problem is the username and password not matching. Everything else is fine. Do you think it could be a problem with the way the password was stored?? 

Big thanks to everybody, again!

Comment: I just echoed back the hashed password and killed the script after filling in the user fields. The password in the database and the password going into the password field are indeed different. ... I think I'm getting warmer.

Comment: Addendum: Never-mind. Changed everything to match and it still says, 'no match.'

Comment: @BernieAllen You should replay back to my answer if you have additional questions  I just happened to look here and notice you updated you question with a reply to me. Your logic is wrong this comparison `} else if ($query > 1) {` makes no sense here as `$query` holds a result set, not an integer value.  If you are trying to compare number of rows as I have done you need to set `mysql_num_rows` to a variable and compare on that variable. You also need to check for case where number of rows = 0 which you are not doing. Finally, run the queries against the database to see what you get.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I solved the problem. It was actually a problem with the way data was being stored in the database. Took some real tweaking, but everything works great, now. Apologies for the way I replied, this is my first question on Stack Overflow. Thanks for all the help! Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should break up your DB query operations in such a manner that you handle the query results in a thorough manner.  Get in the practice of doing this. It will save you lots of time in debugging DB query issues.

Also, there is no need to query the DB twice here (which I assume is what you are doing with your `user_id_from_username()` function call.  Just get rid of this entirely and design your query to get the information you need all at once.

Finally you really should get in the habit of specifying your database connections explicitly. In this case I pass the DB connection into the function.

Putting it all together you end up with something like this:

```
function  login ($username, $password, $db_conn) {
    $username = sanitize ($username);
    $password = md5($password);

    $query = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $db_conn);

    if (false === $result) { // the query failed
        throw new Exception('Database failed with message: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if (0 === $rows) { // no record found
        return false;
    } else if ($rows > 1) { // too many records found.. really your DB indexes should disallow this
        return false;
    }

    $user_id = mysql_result($result, 0 , 'user_id');
    return $user_id;
}
```

Of course you already mentioned that you are aware that your should be using mysqli or PDO.  I can't urge you strongly enough to start using one of those, as mysql is deprecated and you will find you have to start learning one of those others soon anyway, so you might as well start now.